# To find the closest value in the column data in VBA

Tags: vba

Iam writing the vba code to check closest value in the range of data.

Ex:In the worksheet("Sheet6") i have value 31.848
and the worksheet("Z73") i have list values 
65.47
31.74
54.56
0.16
35.71
26.78
56.54
47.62
39.68
1.55
15.87
32.55
17.86

So i need to take the closest value to the 31.848.

Please help me with macro code to do this.

Comment: What code have you already tried?

Comment: If your numbers are sorted in ascending order you could use `MATCH` to return the largest number that is less than your number (31.74 in your example).

Answer (score 0):

The general solution to your problem is as follows):

```
A = 31.848
for each value in your list:
  if |A - B| < C then
    C = |A - B|
  end if
next value
```

your solution will be stored in `C`.

This is pseudo code, it will not solve your problem.

As for actual code, as @braX rightfully stated, we need to know what you have tried so far, where exactly you are stuck and what your vba skills are, so we know where to start with our help.